bash awk: Print lines between two matches and remove newline between two other matches
This is my first post here at stack overflow, so if I'm doing something wrong, please tell me!
I already searched hours for this and can't find a full solution. I can either get one or the other but not both.
I don't want to pipe one awk command to the other.
Instead I want to use a single line awk command.
I have a curl output of a webpage, which I want to change with awk (regular awk, no gawk, mawk etc).
I want to get all lines after the words Downstream Channel Status and before the first occurrence of </table>.
Then between the mentioned matches all line breaks should be removed between <tr align='center'> and </tr>. The lines with mentioned matches don't need to be printed. But I can work around it, if a solution cannot
This is the (shortened) output of curl (which is saved in a variable).
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
<body>
<blockquote>
<p>
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
<tr><th colspan=3><b>Startup Procedure</b></th></tr>
<tr align='center'><td class='hd'>Procedure</td></tr>
</table><br>
</p>

<p>
   <table border='1' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'>
<tr><th colspan=13><b>Downstream Channel Status</b></th></tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td class='hd'>Channel Index</td>
      <td class='hd'>Channel ID</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table><br><br>

</p>

<p>
   <table border='1' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'>
<tr><th colspan=9><b>Upstream Channel Status</b></th></tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td class='hd'>Channel Index</td>
      <td class='hd'>Channel ID</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>9</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>10</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>11</td>
   </tr>
</table><br><br>

</p>

</blockquote>
</body>
</html>

I almost had a solution, but then my PC crashed and now my bash history is gone.
But I tried to combine How to print lines between two patterns, inclusive or exclusive (in sed, AWK or Perl)? and Remove all occurrence of new line between two patterns (sed or awk?)
In the end I want to end up with these lines:
<td class='hd'>Channel Index</td><td class='hd'>Channel ID</td>
<td>1</td><td>193</td>
<td>2</td><td>1</td>
<td>3</td><td>2</td>
<td>4</td><td>3</td>

If you have a solution for me, could you explain how it works?
Thank you!

EDIT
I could find the code, which I thought was lost during the crash. So this is what I came up before posting here:
awk '/Downstream Channel Status/,/\/table/ {gsub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"");print}' File | awk '/tr/{a=1;b="\n";next}/^<\/tr/{a=0;print"";next}a{printf b$0;b="";next}1'


awk is the wrong tool for this job. Please Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Thank you for this hint. And I totally agree with you. However sometimes there are situations where you don't have said XML/HTML parsers. I know it is not optimal.

What exactly version of awk you are using?

I'm using the current macOS 14.4.1 version which is 20200816

As I'm new to posting things at stack overflow. Why has the question received two downvotes? Is it because I'm not using the "correct" tool to get my data? Downvote explanation is "shows no research effort: unclear or not useful". I searched for a solution here and on google for 6 hours before posting, and couldn't find anything. Apart from using awk with this might not be the best way to solve my issue, I think it is still a valid awk question which can be used easily with any other text where you might have the same task.
Can someone elaborate, why people don't like my question?

I didn't downvote but I'd guess it's mostly because you didn't provide your code attempt to solve the problem yourself and this forum exists to help people with their code, not as a free code writing service. Usually questions without code just get downovoted and closed without answers.

Thanks for the hint. Luckily I could reconstruct my code, which was gone from the history after the crash. So I added it to the original question to not get more downvotes.

This works for your input. Obviously, any change in the number of Downstream Channel Status will break the functionality.

Basically set values for each given marker and count their occurrences with set1 for Downstream Channel Status and set2 for <tr align='center'>
Within the wanted block substitute the spaces and printf the lines
Also within the block, every time </tr> is found print a breaking line

% awk '/<\/table>/ && set1 == 1{set1--} 
       /Downstream Channel Status/{set1++} 
       set1 == 1 && set2 > 0 && !/tr.*>/{sub(/^ */,"",$0); printf("%s", $0)} 
       set1 == 1 && set2 > 0 && /<.tr>/{print ""} 
       /<tr align=.center.>/{set2++}' fhtml
<td class='hd'>Channel Index</td><td class='hd'>Channel ID</td>
<td>1</td><td>10</td>
<td>2</td><td>1</td>
<td>3</td><td>2</td>
<td>4</td><td>3</td>

Data
% cat fhtml
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
<body>
<blockquote>
<p>
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
<tr><th colspan=3><b>Startup Procedure</b></th></tr>
</table><br>
</p>

<p>
   <table border='1' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'>
<tr><th colspan=13><b>Downstream Channel Status</b></th></tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td class='hd'>Channel Index</td>
      <td class='hd'>Channel ID</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table><br><br>

</p>

<p>
   <table border='1' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'>
<tr><th colspan=9><b>Upstream Channel Status</b></th></tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td class='hd'>Channel Index</td>
      <td class='hd'>Channel ID</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>9</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>10</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align='center'>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>11</td>
   </tr>
</table><br><br>

</p>

</blockquote>
</body>
</html>


Thank you! It works with 33 lines of Downstream channels.
However it also outputs one empty line before the first line which starts with <td class='hd'>

It shouldn't. You can easily test which print/printf it prints from by adding an additional string to one of the prints. Maybe its a line break from the shell window?

Found the issue for the empty line at the start. I removed a lot of lines for the example curl output I posted. Unfortunately I also removed one <tr align='center'> from the example. So after Startup Procedure there is a line which starts with <tr align='center'>.

OK. After looking at Andre Wildbergs answer I got an idea how to modify/extend the idea/part solution which I posted in my original post.
This is the line of awk which is working fine and can be used for Downstream and Upstream by exchanging the first part of the awk command:
awk '/Downstream Channel Status/{a=1} /<\/table>/{a=0} /<tr/&&a{b=1;next} b && /<\/tr>/{b=0;print""} b{gsub(/^ +/,"");printf "%s", $0}'


/Downstream Channel Status/{a=1} if Downstream Channel Status was matched set var a to 1 (true)
/<\/table>/{a=0} if </table> was matched set same var a back to 0 (false)
/<tr/&&a{b=1;next} if <tr was matched and var a is 1 (true) set var b to 1 (true); then starts the next cycle: next - this is only necessary, because otherwise it would print an empty line first
b && /<\/tr>/{b=0;print""} if var b is 1 (true) and </tr> was matched set var b to 0 (false); then print an empty line: print""
b{gsub(/^ +/,"");printf "%s", $0} replace/remove leading white space; then print  line: printf "%s", $0 - printf is used so all line breaks are removed

This does exactly what I need for my technical setup, where no XML/HTML parser is available.

EDIT: here is the above code formatted legibly by gawk -o-:
awk '
    /Downstream Channel Status/ {
        a = 1
    }
    /<\/table>/ {
        a = 0
    }
    /<tr/ && a {
        b = 1
        next
    }
    b && /<\/tr>/ {
        b = 0
        print ""
    }
    b {
        gsub(/^ +/, "", $0)
        printf "%s", $0
    }
' file


Please don't cram all of your code onto 1 line when posting a question or answer as that just makes it much harder for everyone to be able to read and understand it. I added a legible version of your code to the end of your answer and fixed the syntax error where you were calling printf without arguments.

/\/table/ should be /<\/table>/, and /\/tr/ && a should be b && /<\/tr>/ (yes b, not a) for improved robustness regarding what the regexps match and the context they will match in, and efficiency by only doing the regexp comparison if in the target section of input.

Thank you for the hint. Like I said. It is my first question and answer, so I'm happy to get your input and format it better in the future!
However, one thing I want to uderstand: I the printf command works perfectly fine. Why should I add "%s", $0"? Just to have a proper command because it is defined this way or is there a reason. The output is the same for, no matter if I use it or not.

You're welcome. printf with no arguments can never work, it's a syntax error because printf requires at least 1 argument, a format string. printf $0 would be wrong as it'd treat $0 as the format string and so would fail if $0 contained formatting chars such as %s, so to print $0 without a newline at the end you need to write printf "%s", $0. Just try a) echo '10% off' | awk '{printf}', b) echo '10% off' | awk '{printf $0}' and c) echo '10% off' | awk '{printf "%s", $0}' to see the differences.

a) would give you an error message like awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: printf: no arguments, b) an error message like awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string, and then c) would do what you'd want and output 10% off without a terminating newline.

Thank you for the explanation!
You are right, I get different error messages, but as you said only the last one works. I have no idea why it works in my posted code though. It still works with the single printf command. I changed in my script though!

I'm having a hard time believing that printf on it's own works in any context in any awk but if you have a version of awk that doesn't fail with a syntax error given printf on it's own then you need to get a different awk because if your current one has that bug then it probably has other bugs too.

TXR job:
$ txr extract.txr data.html
<td class='hd'>Channel Index</td><td class='hd'>Channel ID</td>
<td>1</td><td>10</td>
<td>2</td><td>1</td>
<td>3</td><td>2</td>
<td>4</td><td>3</td>

Code in extract.txr:
@(skip)
<tr>@nil<b>Downstream Channel Status</b>@nil
@(repeat)
   <tr@nil
      <td@td1
      <td@td2
@  (do (put-line `<td@td1<td@td2`))
@(until)
</table>@nil
@(end)

We could put the curl command right into the program.

